# Linq-to-Entities: Ordered List aggregated from many-to-many relationship

Tags: group-by, linq-to-entities, many-to-many

Linq to Entities - Many-to-Many Question:

I have a Songs table and a Tags table with a Many-to-Many table between.  I'd like to get a count of Songs for each tag (a tally) and order the Tags starting with least used.  The SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS TimesUsed 
FROM Tags INNER JOIN Song_Tag_Junc STJ ON Tags.ID = STJ.TagID
GROUP by name
ORDER BY COUNT(name)
```

The Entities Song and Tag look like this:

```
public class Song {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea how to accomplish this in Linq to Entities?

Answer (score 0):

So I think I answered my own question.

Since the Tag entity references the Song entity, I was able to write the code below to accomplish ordering the Tags from least used to greatest used:

```
var query = context.Tags.OrderBy(tag => tag.Songs.Count());

List<Tag> list = query.ToList();
```

There is beauty in simplicity!